# Is there a way to identify the same point twice in a plot?

Tags: r

I'm creating a plot of data that should be linear and using identify(x, y) to remove equipment artifacts.  However I want to add the ability to click the point again as a sort of 'undo' and then later in my code remove any duplicated points.  When you attempt to click a point a second time you receive this warning:
'warning: nearest point already identified'
which is expected based on the identify() help page.
Is there any work around for this problem using base graphics or would I have to switch to a more interactive graphics package?  And if so any suggestions?

```
example <- data.table(x = c(1:25), y = c(5+1:14*2, 60, 5+16:25*2))
plot(y~x, data=example)
example_artifact_rm <- example[!identify(example[,x], example[,y])] <- click the artifact and identify it
```

How can I 'unidentify' if I accidentally click the pair (2,9)?

Comment: will `jitter` be useful?

Comment: I strongly advise against "using identify(x, y) to remove outliers". Outliers should be handled with care and not removed subjectively.

Comment: Roland, I almost didn't use the word outlier for the reason that it has a specific meaning.  These points are artifacts of the equipment, not statistical outliers.  Thanks.

Comment: Nishanth, jitter does look like it could be a useful fix with just a line or two of extra code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nishanth, just tried jitter and couldn't make it work for my purposes.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Roland, forgot to actually mention you in the last comment and it's too late to edit

Comment: How about terminating your `identify` run, starting a second run, and re-inserting the intersection of the two sets of data thus generated?

Comment: Has anyone come up with a good solution for this?

Comment: My solution was to replot the graph each time with the original points and the trimmed points, that way you could set it up to reinsert a point if you needed to. That solution would become unwieldy with large plots though.